# Fix container in page and attach to the footer on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to fix the side scroll containing information and attaching it to the footer, while still remain attached if the web page content is changed.

I am getting this problem my right scroll containing information hovers on top of my footer screenshot attached below. [As you can see the information card is coinciding with the footer, please can you tell the solution?][1]

Code goes something like this:

```js
var headerscroll = document.getElementById("headerscroll");
// alert(headerscroll.lenght)
var myScrollFunc = function() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  //alert(y);
  if (y >= 321 && y < 1700) {

    $("#headerscroll").css('background-color', '#323232 ');
    $("#cooper-crash").css('color', 'white');
    $("#cooper-crash").css('font-size', '18px');
    $("#headerscroll").css('height', '98px');
    $("#headerscroll").css('position', 'fixed');
    $("#headerscroll").css('display', 'block');
    $("#learnmore").css('display', 'block');
    $("#learnmore").css('color', '#fff');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('display', 'block');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('top', '28px');
    $("#sendquery").css('display', 'fixed');
    $("#sendquery").css('top', '360px');
    $("#sendquery").css('right', '75px');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('z-index', '20');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('background-color', '#fff');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('border', '1px solid #dedede');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('width', '30%');
    $(".cooper-wishlist").css('display', 'none');
    $(".header-section-color").css('display', 'none');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('position', 'fixed');
    $("#sendquery").css('position', 'fixed');
    $(".cooper_text").css('z-index', '-1');
    $(".cooper-enroll").css('z-index', '1');
    $(".cooper-back").css('top', '-30px');
    $(".cooper-image").css('display', 'none');
    $("#learndetail").css('display', 'none');
    $(".popover").css('display', 'none');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('right', '72px');




  } else if (y > 1700)

  {
    //alert(y);

    $("#headerscroll").css('top', '1700px');
    $("#headerscroll").css('position', 'fixed');

    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('top', '1800px');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('position', 'relative');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('z-index', '-1');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('width', '400px');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('right', '18px');

    $("#sendquery").css('top', '1800px');
    $("#sendquery").css('bottom', '800px');
    $("#sendquery").css('position', 'relative');
    $("#sendquery").css('z-index', '-1');
    $(".footer-first").css('z-index', '20');
    $("#sendquery").css('right', '0px');



  } else {
    $("#headerscroll").css('background-color', 'silver');
    $("#cooper-crash").css('color', 'black');
    $("#cooper-crash").css('font-size', '34px');
    $("#headerscroll").css('height', '300px');
    $("#headerscroll").css('position', 'relative');
    $("#headerscroll").css('display', 'block');

    $(".header-section-color").css('display', 'block');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('position', 'relative');
    $("#sendquery").css('position', 'relative');
    $("#sendquery").css('right', '0px');
    $(".cooper_text").css('z-index', '0');
    $(".cooper-enroll").css('z-index', '0');
    $(".cooper-image").css('display', 'block');
    $(".coopercenter").css('position', 'relative');
    $(".cooper-wishlist").css('display', 'block');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('top', '0px');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('width', '100%');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('z-index', '0');
    $("#learnmore").css('display', 'block');
    $("#learnmore").css('color', '#000');
    $("#sendquery").css('top', '0px');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('border', 'none');
    $(".cooper-back").css('top', '0px');
    $("#learndetail").css('display', 'block');
    $(".customquery").css('left', '0px');
    $(".popover").css('position', 'relative');
    $(".popover").css('display', 'block');
    $("#cooper-enroll-text").css('right', '0px');
  }


};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-4 cooper-enroll">

  <div class="col-sm-12 cooper-enroll-text">
    <div><img src="images/security.jpg" class="cooper-image img-responsive"></div>

    <div id="cooper-enroll-text">
      <div class="cooper-enroll-price ">
        <span class="cooper-text-roll">&#8377;700 &nbsp;&nbsp; </span>
        <span class="cooper-text-roll1 ">&#8377;1150 </span>
        <span class="cooper-off"> &nbsp;&nbsp;92% off </span>
      </div>

      <div class="cooper-enroll-price">
        <a href="order-summary.php">
          <button type="button" class="cooper-enroll-now">
      Enroll Now
     </button><br>
        </a>

      </div>

      <div class="cooper-enroll-price" style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="text-align:center;">30-Day Money-Back Guarantee</span>
      </div>

      <div class="cooper-enroll-price">
        <span style="font-weight:bold;">Includes:</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;34 hours on-demand video</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;78 Articles</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Supplemental Resources</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Full lifetime access</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Access on mobile and TV</span><br>
        <span><i class="fa fa-check cooper-learn-head" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Certificate of Completion</span><br>
      </div>

      <div class="cooper-enroll-price" style="text-align:center; color:blue;" id="ShowCoupon">
        <a href="#"><span> Have a Coupon?</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 enroll" id="couponBox">
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Coupon Code">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sendquery">
    <div class="col-sm-12 customquery">
      <h3 style="font-size:20px">SEND US A QUERY</h3>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No.">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="20" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 361px;margin-bottom:20px;">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want something like this https://www.udemy.com/bootstrap-to-wordpress. 
As you can see in this website, the right side scroll containing image and information, when scrolling to the bottom, it gets attached to the bottom of the webpage (footer).

Comment: There is no screenshot attached can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

just add following jQuery code:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $fixElement = $('.el');

$window.scroll(function() {
  if($window.scrollTop() >= $fixElement.offset().top) {

    /* propably two options */

    // if you will use absolute positioning you have to set top position
    $fixElement.css('top', $window.scrollTop + 10);

    // if you will use fixed positioning you can just add class
    $fixElement.addClass('el--fix');
  } else {
    // default
  }
});
```

I am not exactly specific, but I hope I helped. :)